# How to place a button on a loading animation with Kivy?

Tags: button, kivy, python-3.7

I'm really new to Kivy, i'm trying to make my first app, but i don't really understand how to play with elements and classes...

I'm trying to put a button to stop the sound but it will just stop the animation....

Here's the code, i think i don't code it properly ! :(

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from functools import partial
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

Builder.load_string('''                               
<App_container>: 
    canvas.before:
        PushMatrix
        Rotate:
            angle: root.angle
            axis: 0, 0, 1
            origin: root.center
    canvas.after:
        PopMatrix


    Image:
        id: img_anim
        source: 'logo.png'
        size_hint: 0,0
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
''')

class App_container(FloatLayout):
    angle = NumericProperty(0)
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        #Anim
        super(App_container, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        anim = Animation(angle = 360, duration=2)
        anim2 = Animation(size_hint=(2,2), duration=2)
        anim.start(self)
        anim2.start(self.ids["img_anim"])
        #Son
        self.sound = SoundLoader.load('zik.wav')
        self.sound.loop = True
        self.sound.play()
        #boutonzik
        btn = Button(text ="Push Me !")
        self.add_widget(btn)
        btn.bind(on_press=partial(self.foo, btn))

    def foo(self, instance, *args):
        self.sound.volume=0


class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return App_container()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = TestApp()
    app.run()
```

Comment: You cannot have two `return` statements in your `build()` method.

Comment: I modified my code but still the button will have same behaviour as the animation

Comment: Your modified code works for me. I have changed the audio and image files, but no other changes. Pressing the button just silences the audio and the animation continues. I am using Kivy v1.11.1 and Python v3.6.9 on Ubuntu 18.04. What are you using?

Comment: Python 3.7.7 and kivy 1.11.1 win7 The button doesn't spin for you ? What i want is my image to rotate (it's the app logo) and a button to mute sound (because it's looping) that would stay over

Comment: Yes, the button spins, but pressing the button stops only the audio. Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: I would like the button overlaying the logo to stop the music, so like "above" the logo spinning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the `Button` to not spin, it must not be in the spinning `Layout`. To do this, you can add another `FloatLayout` in your `App_container`, and only spin that `FloatLayout`. The following modification of your code does that:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader

Builder.load_string('''                               
<App_container>:
    FloatLayout:
        # move the angle property into this FloatLayout
        angle: 0.0
        id: rotate_this
        canvas.before:
            PushMatrix
            Rotate:
                angle: self.angle
                axis: 0, 0, 1
                origin: root.center
        canvas.after:
            PopMatrix

        Image:
            id: img_anim
            source: 'logo.png'
            size_hint: 0,0
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
    Button:
        text: 'Push Me'
        on_press: root.foo(self)
        size_hint: 0.1,0.1
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.5}
''')


class App_container(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        #Anim
        super(App_container, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        anim = Animation(angle = 360, duration=2)
        anim2 = Animation(size_hint=(2,2), duration=2)

        # rotate the FloatLayout with id "rotate_this"
        anim.start(self.ids["rotate_this"])

        # animate the "img_anim"
        anim2.start(self.ids["img_anim"])
        #Son
        self.sound = SoundLoader.load('zik.wav')
        self.sound.loop = True
        self.sound.play()

    def foo(self, instance, *args):
        self.sound.volume=0


class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return App_container()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = TestApp()
    app.run()
```

So the `FloatLayout` spins, but the `Button` does not, since it is not inside the spinning `FloatLayout`.

Comment: Thanks so much ! I'm so noob on Kivy ^^' Exactly what i was expecting ! I start to understand better how it works !